# Fast way to find Javascript source file in debugger?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, rstudio

RStudio uses Chrome Devtools for debugging support in its Viewer pane.  (It is labelled as "RStudio Devtools", but I'm not sure to what extent it is customized besides that).  You can open its window using Right-click "Inspect Element".

When developing a display that uses Javascript, the source pane in Devtools is very useful for setting breakpoints, single stepping, etc.

One thing that is fairly inconvenient is finding the line where I want to set a breakpoint.  Once I have the source file open searching it is easy, but getting to the right source file is hard.  Typically after I go to the source pane, I see something like this:

[image: screenshot]

I know the name of the file I want to debug, but it's buried several levels below `index.html` in the list of files on the left.  Is there a way to quickly search this hierarchy of files for a filename, so that I don't need to open all the levels down to the file I want?  For example, I might want to debug `htmlwidgets.js`:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll note in the "sources" pane that, if you have no open files, you'll see a message in the middle that indicates you can type `Command + P` (or `Ctrl + P` on Windows/Linux) to open a file.  When clicked, this will open a text box that will fuzzy search across the names of all source files.  Type the filename there and it should be in the first results.  You can navigate to it with the keyboard and select it with `<Enter>/<return>`, or simply clicked with the mouse.

[image: Image of the Google Chrome Developer Tools Source Pane, with text stating that command P will open a file and command shift p will run a command.]

Comment: Thanks!  I've never noticed that message before:  I think RStudio usually automatically opens `rstudio-0.js`.

Comment: No problem-- happy coding!